# Can I define a custom format for userId in keycloak server?

Tags: keycloak

Can I define custom format for userId in keycloak server?

Example : FirstName_lastName_randomInt

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating custom user id is not possible currently in Keycloak. If you take a look at [source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.java), you can see that user id is auto generated at the time of new user creation and no setters are provided for the same. And that makes sense as you are free to create **username** in the format you wish. 
So you should create username according to your requirement.

Comment: Yes it's right. I means username in my question.
Thank you a lot.